# How to get the ios document/library path through Qt5?

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I used find my ios app's document/library path by going up starts from `QApplication::applicationDirPath()`.

However from iOS 7/8, the bundle path is moved away from data path.

So how can I get my app's writable paths through Qt C++ only? Is there a correct way that packed with Qt?

I don't want to write on `APPROOT`'s document. And I understand that I can write objective-c codes to find the path.

So my app is installed at:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX/

What I want to get is

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/YYYY/Documents
>
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/YYYY/Library

note that the bundle's long id (the XXXX) is different from Data's (the YYYY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to take the document or any other standard library directories path, use `QStandardPaths` from `Qt5`:

```
QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation
```

For other paths consider to read the official Qt docs about [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html)

Comment: I test this in simulator but I get xxx/Library/Application Support. I edited my question. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Did you try each of these paths? At first, they can return not exactly one path but a few. Secondly, try them all because it may not be shown in the Qt docs. I am away from my Mac now, can only test this evening. If you would be unable to find it anyway, ask your question on [Qt's bugtracker]https://bugreports.qt.io/)

Comment: Sorry I found that it works on iOS. It's weird on simulator though. Thanks!